# Add div while ajax loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I put this code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $("#loading-image").show();
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  $("#loading-image").hide();
});
```

on the top of the page...

and I have HTML:

```
<body style="">
<div id="loading-image" style="width:100%; height:100%; background:#ccc; display:none;"></div>
```

But I dont see ID loading image on ajax... What can be a problem here?

Comment: Does your #loading-image need to have an image as a child, and that image's source (URL) set before showing the div?

Comment: but look on the div style - width and height and background ...

Comment: Try `<body style="position:relative;">`

Comment: dont work with body position relative

Comment: you need to use document.ready

Comment: Also, here's a jsfiddle I whipped together: http://jsfiddle.net/wS8Ec/1/ --> the parent elements body and html need to have the width, heigh pcts set to 100%.  The button is used to simulate the ajaxStart/ajaxStop functions.  (Note that if I omit the body and html style from the css, it doesn't work)

Comment: You need to show the image immediately before the AJAX function and then hide it as part of the success function.

Comment: And here's an updated fiddle that shows the styling entirely in the html: http://jsfiddle.net/wS8Ec/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't seems to have anything wrong, make sure that those methods are in fact beeing called whenever you use ajax, put a breakpoint in the element inspector. Also check if when you manually remove display:none from the "loading-image" div you can see it on the screen, just to be sure.

Comment: This also dont work:  $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  alert ('RADI');
});

Comment: MY CODE WORK WHEN I PUT THEM ON BOTTOM ON THE PAGE :) FUNNY

Comment: Well, then your problem probably is in the ajax code that you didn't post. Check if it is correct. Also check if a variable named "global" is on your ajax code and it isn't false, if it is not there then by default is true. It is a flag that allows the methods ajaxStop and ajaxStart to be called. Check the documentation for more information [link]https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: If the problem is that it only ran when you put it on the bottom of the page, then you need to see the comment about wrapping your code in a document ready function like `$(function(){...})` similar to what @Volte describes in his second code block.

Answer (score 2):

From the limited amount that you posted, it doesn't look like you're actually making an AJAX request. http://jsfiddle.net/volte/A66C8/

Try then making an ajax call when the page loads:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
});
```

Disclaimer: I have not tested this. Pulled from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

In addition, make sure you wrap those methods in an onload. Most people do:

```
(function() {
  //... your code here ...
  //... will be run on load...
});
```

Comment: `$.ajax()` will make the ajax call.  However, [`.ajaxStart()`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) will wrap the ajax start event.  The code that showed the ajax call may not have been relevant to the error.

Comment: Dunno why my answer got down voted. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/volte/A66C8/ it works just fine when you actually make an ajax call, otherwise why would it ever show?